# Show Duplicate Error Message in Error list in View : Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Below is my code to check if the record is duplicate or not.**

```
$Category = \App\Models\Category_Model
           ::where("Category", "=", $request->input('Category'))->first();
if($Category != null) {
    return 'Duplicate';
}
```

**Is there any way to inject this error message in the validation rule in such a way that this error message appears in View the error list in below section?**

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: have a look at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Solution:1**

## [**Reference : unique:Name of the Table:**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-unique)

Make sure the database table contains Unique Constraint.

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:100|min:5'
]);
```

## **Solution:2**

```
$Category = \App\Models\Category_Model
            ::where("Category", "=", $request->input('Category'))->first();

if($Category != null) {

    $v->errors()->add('Duplicate', 'Duplicate Category found!');

    return redirect('Create-Category')
                ->withErrors($v)
                ->withInput();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

Create **CategoryFormRequest** class

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class CategoryFormRequest extends Request {

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        $rules = [
            'Category' => ' required|unique:categories,Category',
        ];
        if ($this->method() == 'PUT') {
            $rules['Category'] = 'required|unique:categories,Category,' . $this->category;
        }
        return $rules;
    }

}
```

Your controller code

```
use App\Http\Requests\CategoryFormRequest as CategoryFormRequest;
......
......
 public function store(CategoryFormRequest  $request) {
  .......
  ....... 
}
```

Ref:- [Request](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests) class in laravel

Answer (score 0):

You could return a view with errors like this:

```
return view('my_view')->withErrors(['Duplicate Record.']);
```